# Django Rest Framework 3: Uploading files without request.FILES

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I noticed that I with Django Rest Framework 3 no longer have to specify `files=request.FILES` when using a serializer in file uploads. According to the [release notes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/), `request.data` now contains all the data. So, I simply removed `files=request.FILES`, and went from:

```
serializer = MediaSerializer(
    theMedia,
    data = postData,
    files = request.FILES,
    partial = True
)
```

to:

```
serializer = MediaSerializer(
    theMedia,
    data = postData,
    partial = True
)
```

In my Django API app, I have a /media/ endpoint to which one can `PUT` the files `photo` and `filename`. When trying to `PUT` files with the change I made, the files never touch my custom storage. The header is correct (Content-Type: multipart/form-data), and it all worked fine in DRF 2.x.

I Noticed that I need to use the `MultiPartParser` in my view to be able to use the `fileField`, so now my view uses `parser_classes = (JSONParser, MultiPartParser)`.

Here is the section of the serializer handeling the files:

```
class MediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photo = serializers.ImageField(
        max_length = None,
        required = False,
        allow_empty_file = False)
    filename = serializers.FileField(
        max_length = None,
        required = False,
        allow_empty_file = False)
    ...

class Meta:
    model = Media
    fields = (
        'photo',
        'filename'
    )
```

Maybe I should also mention that I have turned off `UPLOADED_FILES_USE_URL` in the settings.

My question is: What is it that I am missing out in DRF3 - Why does the uploaded files never touch my custom storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django REST Framework 3 deprecated the `request.DATA` and `request.FILES` properties [in favor of a unified `request.data` property](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#request-objects). The serializers were also updated as well to remove the `files` argument, still maintaining the `data` argument which should be `request.data` instead of `request.DATA`.

In your example, you appear to be altering the incoming data, as you have it set to a variable `postData`, which isn't included. Most likely, you are not using `request.data` and the issue is that you are only getting the data without the files, instead of the full data you are expecting.

You should be able to verify this by logging the values of `request.data` and `postData`, and check that `request.data` contains the image you are trying to send.

Comment: Kevin, you are very right. I alter the data: postData = request.data.copy(). Copying this way does not include the files. Thank you for pointing me towards the right direction - I appriciate it alot!